# How to have multiple input fields in the same input box

Tags: powershell

I would like to have a tech enter in the username and the group name but in *one input box*. Anyone willing to tell me how to do this?

```
Function add-togroup{

    #Adds members to group in AD

    #$users = Read-Host "Enter a username"
    Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic;
    $value = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter username', 
    'Username')
    $value2 = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter group 
    name', 'XA Group','')
    $group_membership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $users | select name | 
    format-table -auto
    foreach($u in $value)
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember $value2 -Members $u
    } 

    Write-Host $group_membership
}
```

So I am capable of using multiple dialogs in sequence but it would make for a  better user experience if I could roll this into one single box /form.

Comment: Are you asking how to split a string then? I don't understand exactly what you want or see an attempt to change that. Also drop that `Format-Table` as it is not doing anything useful for you

Comment: Instead of having two separate input popups I would like to have one with two places to enter information. One for username and the second to enter group

Comment: Ah ok. You need [something like this then](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx). You need to roll your own dialog in this case.

Comment: I'm fairly new to powershell and really new to input boxes. Can you help me out with what the code should look like

Comment: I removed the extra information in the post and tried to clarify the requirements as I understood them. I also adjusted the code space for readability. While I encourage you to keep most of the edits you are welcome to rollback if you feel this is overdoing it.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not satisfied with the basic forms available then one option you have is to roll your own in PowerShell with .Net forms. Just to show an example that you can build from...

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter" -or $_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){
        $objForm.Close()
    }
})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the information in the space below:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objTextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,70) 
$objTextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox2) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void]$objForm.ShowDialog()

$objTextBox.Text
$objTextBox2.Text
```

The borrows **heavily** from the [great primer on the subject on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx) which you should read as it walks you though this better. I removed some of the variable population logic as it was flawed and added another text box. The last two lines return the values entered by the "user". Aside from the addition of the text box I have left most other cosmetic changes up to you to help you get a better understanding of what is involved here.

Keep in mind the locations and sizes of newly added objects and be sure you actually add it to the form.

Since there is not GUI for form building it can seem daunting but its not really that hard to do. You just need to experiment. If you are so inclined there are 3rd party tools that will help with that.